# Determine time spent waiting for stats to be updated - SQL05/08

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone know how to specifically identify the portion of the overall compilation time that any queries spent waiting on statistics (after stats are deemed stale) to be updated in SQL 2005/2008? (I do not desire to turn on the async thread to update stats in the background just in case that point of conversation comes up). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quantum,

I doubt that level of detail and granularity is exposed in SQL Server. What is the real question here? Are you trying to gauge how long it takes for the queries to re-compile when the stats are deemed stale to the normal compilation time? Is this a one off request or are you planning to put something in production and measure the difference over a period of time?

If it is former then, you can get that info by figuring out the time taken individually (set statistics time on) and combing them together. If it is latter then I am NOT sure there is anything that is currently available in SQL Server.

PS: I haven't checked Extended Events (in DENALI) in detail for this activity but there could be something there for you. You may want to check that out if you are really interested.

Comment: Thanks for the information Sankar. Yes, I was debating turning the async thread on but I wanted to possibly get some level of exposure as to any queries at all that specifically waited on statistics to be updated. It wasn't to address a one-off issue; it was to get a general picture of when this might have occurred. I agree - I didn't think anything is available but wanted to ask the experts out there. I will keep a lookout for such items in Denali. Thanks! :)